# Code Geass - What is the song playing in Episode 1: The Day a New Demon was Born

Tags: music, code-geass

Does anybody know what song is playing at 15:12? (The introduction of C.C.). I've looked at all of the unreleased songs, but many of the OST is blocked due to copyright. Apologies if the answer is obvious.

Answer (score 2):

I found the song. it's "The First Signature".